# How to pass integer vector from shell?

Tags: c++, shell

I want to pass an integer array/vector as shell argument? Below is my last attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
//using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char dummy;
    std::vector<int> argument(argc-1);
    std::cout<<argc<<std::endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= argc; ++i)
    {
        dummy=*(*(argv+1)+i);
        argument[i-1]=std::stoi(dummy);
    }

    std::cout<<argument.size()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘stoi(char&)’

Is there any simpler way to do it?
basically run program as:

> ./executable {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

and intialize an array/vector in programme with those values?

Comment: `std::stoi(dummy);` wants a `std::string`, not a `char`

Comment: [FYI] `for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements_to iterate; ++i)` is more common place then `for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_elements_to iterate; ++i)`

Comment: Don't perform pointer addition for the sole purpose of dereferencing.  `argv[1][i]` is so much easier to comprehend than `*(*(argv+1)+i)`... the mistake is much easier to see.

Comment: I declared dummy as std::string, it compiled but gives error at runtime as "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'". @nanthan yes i understand the convention but i was so desperate that was trying every little thing i can think of to make it work! Even id does work, I would be deeply interested in knowing simpler way to pass vector as shell arguement

Comment: @ipcamit you traded something that compiled but had a logic error that could be debugged for something that did not compile. This is almost always a sucker bet. [Use the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that comes with your development environment first to determine the cause of the logic error, then change the code to fix the error. Changing the code without understanding the mistake is sometimes called "[Shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging)".  You may hit the target, but you probably make a real mess of it in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolving the compiler error is a waste of time. OP had the right idea initially using `std::string dummy;`, so let's stick with that and figure out what went wrong.

First off lets assume 4 arguments: `1 12 123 1234` and examine the range of the 4 loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= argc; ++i)
```

Because OP starts the loop at 1, I assume they know that the first argument is the command executed. Great start.

But `i <= argc` will allow the `i` to range from 1 to 5. `argv` is valid from 0 to 4. That means undefined behaviour was invoked accessing `argv[5]` and Crom only knows what happens after that. Very likely `dummy` got loaded with garbage from `argv[5]` and `std::stoi` could not parse this garbage into an `int`. This is only speculation. Determining the behaviour of undefined behaviour is a waste of time. It might be different next time. It might even look like it worked next time.

So the first thing to do is get rid of the out of bounds read.

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
```

Now we have an `i` with a range of 1 to 4 and everything stays in bounds.

Next, we can clean up

```
dummy=*(*(argv+1)+i);
```

since we aren't tying to fit it into a `char` anymore. The simplest is

```
std::string dummy(argv[i]);
```

which declares `string` `dummy` and initializes it to contain one command line argument. Can this be done faster? Yeah, but this is stupidly easy to read. Start with easy and only go into the difficult if easy doesn't meet the program requirements. The only change I would make here until forced is change `dummy` to a more descriptive name.

Even simpler you could

```
argument[i-1]=std::stoi(argv[i]);
```

But I prefer the `dummy` approach at least for now. It has a major debugging advantage: You can print or use the debugger to inspect the value of `dummy` before `std::stoi` throws an exception because `dummy` can't be converted.

The resulting code:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> argument(argc-1);
    std::cout<<argc<<std::endl; 

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
        std::string dummy(argv[i]);
        argument[i-1]=std::stoi(dummy);
    }

    std::cout<<argument.size()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

called with `./executable  1 12 123 1234` the output will be

```
5
4
```

5 input arguments and 4 items in the vector because the command is discarded.

Figuring out how to handle the curly braces in

```
./executable {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I'm going to leave to OP to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make complex simply use

```
    argument[i-1]=std::stoi(argv[i]); in place of 

    dummy=*(*(argv+1)+i);
    argument[i-1]=std::stoi(dummy);
```

we know that array of size n stores element from location 0 to location n-1. 
 argc is the number of strings when you run the program including your executable file name we know that argv is array of strings(character sequence) so at location zero in argv is a executable file name. that is why start for loop from location i=1, and we need to run for loop i=1 to i < argc( means till i<=argc-1)

try following program

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
  {
  char dummy;
  std::vector<int> argument(argc-1);
  std::cout<<argc<<std::endl;

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
  {
      //   dummy=*(*(argv+1)+i);
    // argument[i-1]=std::stoi(dummy);

     argument[i-1]=std::stoi(argv[i]);
   }

  std::cout<<argument.size()<<std::endl;

 return 0;
 }
```